# What is the difference between Requests and Requests-html?

Tags: python-requests, python-requests-html

I have to give seminar on Requests and Requests-html. I am searching that but can't find any website. Both Requests and Requests-html has same methods but what is the difference

Answer (score 0):

[Requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) helps you to parse contents of a webpage (aka web-scraping). You can connect to a webpage and parse its contents like links, raw data, search for specific terms. Generally, it is used for data analytical purpose and requires less technical expertise than `requests`.

[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) helps you to make HTTP calls programatically. You can send GET/POST et al requests just like curl commands and receive response to be processed by certain logic. Generally backend API developers use it and requires technical knowledge of how HTTP works.